# Refresh page to retrieve Woocommerce setting

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I am writing an extension to Woocommerce and have a settings tab with an 'enable_extension' checkbox. This is setup with the conventional Woocommerce settings layout and the standard 'save settings' button.

When the checkbox is enabled, I would like to have an extra menu item appear under the Woocommerce menu item list.

However, when the 'save settings' button is pressed, I must refresh the page in order for the menu item to appear. The same happens when I disable the checkbox and press 'save settings' .. I must refresh the page in order for the menu item to be removed.

I am trying to hook into the POST requests in the Woocommerce settings.

I have noticed that when the 'enable_extension' checkbox is enabled, the post request includes

```
$_POST['enable_extension'] = 1
```

However, the opposite is not true when the checkbox is disabled. I.e. there is no

```
$_POST['enable_extension'] = 0
```

In the POST request that I can hook into. How would you go about this in a manner whereby I wouldn't have to perform a force refresh of the page?

Comment: A checkbox is not submitted at all if it's unchecked. so `if (!array_key_exists('enable_extension', $_POST))` is how to check for a checkbox not checked.

Comment: @miken32 I now have this working so that the sub menu appears when the post request contains 'enable_extension' from an enabled checkbox. If I disable the checkbox, I must refresh the page in order for the sub-menu item to be removed.

Answer (score 0):

Using @miken32 comment as inspiration:

```
if (!array_key_exists('enable_extension', $_POST)){
      return
} else if (woocommerce_option || (array_key_exists('enable_extension', $_POST))){
      add sub menu...
}
```

gets the functionality I need.